# .NET ACL Auditing in Realtime

Tags: .net, permissions, real-time, acl, audit

I want to track live changes to ACLs using .NET without using the EventLog variation.

Does anyone know if this is possible and howso? I've been searching for about a week without any helpful results.

Thanks,

JSchmitz

Comment: Also, I need it to be able to tell me these things:

1. Who changed the ACL
2. From which Workstation the ACL was modified
3. When it was changed

Answer (score 0):

You should just need a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), with the `NotifyFilter` property set to [Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx).

You can then call [GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1h6d4k4.aspx) to get the current ACL for the changed file/folder.